# BackboneJS - Possible callback of super class of multi level inheritance?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a setup of multi level backbone inheritance, but would like to call back of the previous super class. Not sure if is possible.

**Scenario:**

BasicView -> MediumView -> HardView

Where I would love that when HardView created, it will loops to call previous super class initialize function.

**Example is here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/bwB9W/

Comment: There's a discussion of this topic here: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-3143358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no implicit references to the superclass in standard JavaScript - you have to explicitly call the supertype's methods

```
var Basic = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('base');
    }        
});


var Medium = Basic.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(Basic.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments));
        console.log('medium');
    }        
});

var Hard = Medium.extend({
    initialize:function(){        
        console.log(Medium.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments));
        console.log('hard');
    }        
});


var hard = new Hard();

​
```